# How to use Async/Await in Silverlight 5 (VB)

Tags: vb.net, web-services, silverlight, async-await

I'm trying to call a web service and have my code wait for that service to return a result (or timeout). My project is Silverlight 5 with Web Services using .NET 4.0 and I'm running this project under VS 2012 with the Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.16\lib\sl4\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll ... Task.Extensions.dll ... and Extensions.Silverlight.dll.

This is how I've been doing it and it's working, but I'm trying to figure out how to change my code so that I can use the Async/Await process.  The web service reference is configured to return ObservableCollection and Generic.Dictionary with Reuse types in all referenced assemblies.

Some of my code I need to convert to Async/Await:

```
    Private _Units As Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.Units)
Public Property Units() As Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.Units)
    Get
        Return _Units
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.Units))
        _Units = value
        OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Units"))
    End Set
End Property


   Public Sub ReadUnits()

    Try

        ' Client is required
        If Not Me.Client Is Nothing Then

            ' User is required
            If Not Me.User Is Nothing Then

                ' Must be a real Client
                If Me.Client.ClientID > 0 Then

                    ' My have a sites
                    If Not Me.Site Is Nothing Then

                        ' Call the web service relative to where this application is running
                        Dim webServiceURI As New Uri("../WebServices/Unit.svc", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                        Dim webServiceAddress As New EndpointAddress(webServiceURI)

                        ' Setup web Service proxy
                        Dim wsUnits As New DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.UnitClient
                        wsUnits.Endpoint.Address = webServiceAddress

                        ' Add event handler so we can trap for web service completion
                        AddHandler wsUnits.LoadsCompleted, AddressOf LoadUnitsCompleted

                        ' Call web service to get Sites the user has access to
                        wsUnits.LoadsAsync(Me.Client, Me.Site.SiteID, Me.Size.SizeID, Me.RentalType.RentalTypeID, Me.UnitState)

                    End If

                End If

            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim Problem As New DC.SL.Tools.Errors(ex)

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub LoadUnitsCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.LoadsCompletedEventArgs)

    Try

        If Not IsNothing(e.Result) Then

            Me.Units = e.Result

            If Me.Units.Count > 0 Then
                Me.Unit = Me.Units.Item(0)
            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim Problem As New DC.SL.Tools.Errors(ex)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Still not getting this to work ... here is what I have now, but the problem remains ... UI thread execution continues and does NOT wait for the Web Service call to finish.

Calling code:

```
ReadUnitsAsync().Wait(3000)
```

Here is the updated code:

```
    Public Async Function ReadUnitsAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)

    Dim Results As Object = Await LoadReadUnitsAsync()

    Return True

End Function

Public Function LoadReadUnitsAsync() As Task(Of System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.Units))

    LoadReadUnitsAsync = Nothing

    Dim tcs = New TaskCompletionSource(Of System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.Units))

    ' Client is required
    If Not Me.Client Is Nothing Then

        ' User is required
        If Not Me.User Is Nothing Then

            ' Must be a real Client associated
            If Me.Client.ClientID > 0 Then

                ' Only get associated sites IF we don't have any defined
                If Not Me.Site Is Nothing Then

                    ' Call the web service relative to where this application is running
                    Dim webServiceURI As New Uri("../WebServices/Unit.svc", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                    Dim webServiceAddress As New EndpointAddress(webServiceURI)

                    ' Setup Site web Service proxy
                    Dim wsUnits As New DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.UnitClient
                    wsUnits.Endpoint.Address = webServiceAddress

                    ' Add event handler so we can trap for web service completion
                    AddHandler wsUnits.LoadUnitsCompleted, Sub(s, e)
                                                               If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
                                                                   tcs.TrySetException(e.Error)
                                                               ElseIf e.Cancelled Then
                                                                   tcs.TrySetCanceled()
                                                               Else
                                                                   tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result)
                                                               End If
                                                           End Sub

                    '' Set Busy Status
                    'BusyStack.Manage(ProcessManager.StackAction.Add, "ReadUnits", Me.IsWorking, Me.IsWorkingMessage)

                    ' Call web service to get Sites the user has access to
                    wsUnits.LoadUnitsAsync(Me.Client, Me.Site.SiteID, Me.Size.SizeID, Me.RentalType.RentalTypeID, Me.UnitState)

                    Return tcs.Task

                End If

            End If

        End If

    End If

End Function
```

So here is the final code (abbreviated) that seems to be working to my goals (aka waiting for a Web Service to finish before proceeding).

```
Public Class UIUnits
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Public Async Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)

    Dim propertyEventHandler As PropertyChangedEventHandler = PropertyChangedEvent

    Try

        If propertyEventHandler IsNot Nothing Then

            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, e)

            Select Case e.PropertyName

                Case "Size"

                    Await ReadUnitsAsync()

        DoSomethingElseAfterWebServiceCallCompletes()

                Case Else

            End Select

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim problem As New DC.SL.Tools.Errors(ex)

    End Try

End Sub
```

...

```
Private _Units As Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.Units)
Public Property Units() As Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.Units)
    Get
        Return _Units
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.Units))
        _Units = value
        OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Units"))
    End Set
End Property
```

...

```
Public Async Function ReadUnitsAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)

    Me.Units = Await LoadReadUnitsAsync()
    Return True

End Function
```

...

```
Public Function LoadReadUnitsAsync() As Task(Of System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.Units))

    LoadReadUnitsAsync = Nothing

    Dim tcs = New TaskCompletionSource(Of System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.Units))

    ' Client is required
    If Not Me.Client Is Nothing Then

        ' User is required
        If Not Me.User Is Nothing Then

            ' Must be a real Client associated
            If Me.Client.ClientID > 0 Then

                ' Only get associated sites IF we don't have any defined
                If Not Me.Site Is Nothing Then

                    ' Call the web service relative to where this application is running
                    Dim webServiceURI As New Uri("../WebServices/Unit.svc", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                    Dim webServiceAddress As New EndpointAddress(webServiceURI)

                    ' Setup web Service proxy
                    Dim wsUnits As New DC.SL.Services.WebServiceUnit.UnitClient
                    wsUnits.Endpoint.Address = webServiceAddress

                    ' Add event handler so we can trap for web service completion
                    AddHandler wsUnits.LoadUnitsCompleted, Sub(s, e)
                                                               If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
                                                                   tcs.TrySetException(e.Error)
                                                               ElseIf e.Cancelled Then
                                                                   tcs.TrySetCanceled()
                                                               Else
                                                                   tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result)
                                                               End If
                                                           End Sub

                    ' Call web service 
                    wsUnits.LoadUnitsAsync(Me.Client, Me.Site.SiteID, Me.Size.SizeID, Me.RentalType.RentalTypeID, Me.UnitState)

                    Return tcs.Task

                End If

            End If

        End If

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Don't you have to remove the added handle to LoadUnitsCompleted to avoid multiple invocation on the next execution?

Comment: Ok, and?  Sorry for frustration here, but I'm getting all kinds of mixed information about how to call a web service via Silverlight 5.  Part of the problem is that all codes samples are in C# ... so I have to convert them to VB and they often don't convert correctly.  And finally, there seems to be some confusion around what tools/technology I'm using as many of the samples are specific to .NET 4.5.  In Silverlight 5 any web service references can't "generate task-based operations".  I was hoping someone could convert my simple sample which might help turn the light bulb on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it's probably easiest to convert from the lowest level and work your way up. First, you need to define your own [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx)-friendly extension methods on your service. VS will generate these for you if you are doing desktop development, but unfortunately it will not do this for Silverlight.

The MSDN docs describe [how to wrap EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178.aspx#EAP) ([EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx) is the pattern that uses `*Async` methods with matching `*Completed` events). If you have APM methods, it's even easier to [wrap those into TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178.aspx#ApmToTap) ([APM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx) is the pattern that uses `Begin*`/`End*` method pairs).

Once you have a wrapper, e.g., `LoadUnitsTaskAsync`, change your method to call that instead of `LoadUnitsAsync` and `Await` the result. This will require your `ReadUnits` method to be `Async`, so change it to a `Task`-returning `Function` (and change its name from `ReadUnits` to `ReadUnitsAsync`). Next change all callers of `ReadUnitsAsync` so they `Await` its result. Repeat until you reach an actual event handler, which may be `Async Sub` (do not use `Async Sub` for any intermediate methods; use `Async Function ... As Task` instead).

Comment: Stephen, thank you, great information.  Let me digest and try out your suggestions.

Comment: hmmm ... can you point me in a direction to find out what "TAP-friendly extension methods are for Web Services for Silverlight"?  Not finding anything useful. ... I was assuming this is done via the Web Service reference (configure references) but this is set to "reuse types in all referenced assemblies".

Comment: I included a link to TAP in my answer. The general idea is that you write an extension method that uses `TaskCompletionSource` or `TaskFactory` to wrap existing asynchronous APIs. A TAP-friendly method is one that returns a `Task` or `Task(of TResult)`. Unfortunately, the Web Service reference will refuse to automatically generate TAP-friendly methods for Silverlight, so you have to write your own (as extension methods).

Comment: I'm not making the connections here ... I can see I'll have to do a lot of reading.  I thought it was going to be a lot easier to implement.

Comment: No progress ... removed the handler, created Async Function to return Task(Of myUnitsObservableCollection) ... Return Await wsUnits.LoadsAsync(...) IDE says "Expression does not produce a Value".  So tried to configure web service reference to "Generate task-based operations" but this is grayed out (not available) for SL5 Projects.

Comment: Oh well, guess I'm just too lost ... something I thought would be relatively simple is not.

Comment: I have another link in my answer to [TAP wrapping EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178.aspx#EAP). There's a code sample there that shows how to create a TAP extension method around the existing method/event pair.

Comment: Updated my original question with adjusted code, that unfortunately still doesn't achieve my goals of waiting for a web service to complete before proceeding.

Comment: You shouldn't call `Wait` on it - that means to block the UI thread until it completes. Instead of `Wait`, use `Await`.

Comment: Silverlight 5 will not let me use Await outside of a method that doesn't have Async??

Comment: It's natural for `Async` to "grow". So all methods that call this one should become `Async`, then all methods that call *those*, etc. I cover this in the last part of my answer.

Comment: Hmmm...ok, added Async to my Public Sub OnPropertyChanged so it now reads Public Async Sub OnPropertyChanged ... which no allows me to use Await.  And it actually does seem to work per my goals ... but I get a sense this is somehow not the right way to do this?  Any "gotcha's" I need to be aware of?

Comment: If `OnPropertyChanged` is an event handler (or overriding a `Sub` from a base class), then that's fine. As a general rule of thumb, prefer `Async Function ... as Task` instead of `Async Sub`, but in some situations you don't have a choice about it (like event handlers or overriding base class methods).

Comment: Thanks for your help Stephen, eventually got there. ;)  I posted updated sample in my original thread in case anyone was a lost as I was using Async and Await in SL5 projects.  I'm still somewhat baffled as to why Microsoft didn't simply add a Sync option in the first place ... so my "LoadUnitsAsync" web service call would simply be "LoadUnitsSync".  Seems to me a much easier change to accomplish the same end goals.

Comment: Just as I thought I had this working ... there is a Gotcha, I can't use Async on any method that uses ByRef.  Which is kinda big problem, so sadly all this work was for no gain.

Comment: True. I usually convert `ByRef` methods into methods that take a regular argument and return a `Tuple`.

Answer (score 2):

I used [this](http://10rem.net/blog/2012/05/22/using-async-and-await-in-silverlight-5-and-net-4-in-visual-studio-11-with-the-async-targeting-pack) library to achieve async await in my Silverlight 5 project